# How to solve Undefined controll sequence in document class (.cls) file

Tags: documentclass-writing, documentclass

I have to write a document class with 2 parameters (one gives a logo and one a chess board). The code for the two parameters are working fine but i get some errors and i dont know how to fix them.
Every Error is in Line 119 ( `\ProcessOptions\relax` ) but this doesn't make any sense.
I read that the Latex hooks error can be fixed if something isnt up to datebut i updated everything today so this isnt the problem.
I dont know if i have a typo (cant see one) or something else is wrong in my class so i put u my errors and my .cls and my .tex down below.

[image: Latex Errors]

.cls

```
%----------------------------------------%
%       Important Stuff for Class        %
%----------------------------------------%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{HTWself}[2022/21/27 Example class]



%-------------------%
%       Packages    %
%-------------------%
\RequirePackage[RGB]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
\newboolean{cover}


\definecolor{htw}{RGB}{125, 173, 24}


\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[german]{babel}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{blindtext}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{wrapfig}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}


\RequirePackage{pstricks}
\RequirePackage{multido}
\RequirePackage{pst-plot}
\RequirePackage{auto-pst-pdf}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont}

%---------------%
%   Parameters  %
%---------------%

\DeclareOption{htwLogo}{
\setboolean{cover}{true}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,0)(14,5)


\multido{\iA=1+2}{2}{
    \multido{\iB=1+1}{2}{
        \psset{origin={\iA ,\iB}}
        \psframe[linecolor=htw,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=htw](1,1)
        }
    }
\multido{\iA=8+2}{3}{
    \multido{\iB=2+1}{2}{
    \psset{origin={\iA ,\iB}}
    \psframe[linecolor=htw,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=htw](1,1)
    }
}

\multido{\iA=2+4}{2}{
    \multido{\iB=3+0}{1}{
    \psset{origin={\iA ,\iB}}
    \psframe[linecolor=htw,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=htw](1,1)
    }
}

\multido{\iA=6+7}{2}{
    \multido{\iB=1+0}{1}{
    \psset{origin={\iA ,\iB}}
    \psframe[linecolor=htw,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=htw](1,1)
    }
}
\rput[b](7.4,0){\Large{Hochschule für Technik und Wirtschaft Berlin}}
\psframe[linecolor=htw,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=htw](1,4)(2,5)
\psframe[linecolor=htw,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=htw](5,2)(6,5)
\psframe[linecolor=htw,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=htw](9,1)(12,2)

\psline[linecolor=htw,linearc=0.5](3,4)(4,4)(4,3)
\psline[linecolor=htw,linearc=0.5](5,2)(5,1)(6,1)
\psline[linecolor=htw,linearc=0.5](8,2)(8,1)(9,1)

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}}

\DeclareOption{htwWeiteres}{
\setboolean{cover}{false}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(8,8)
\psframe(8,8)
    \multido{\iA=0+2,\iC=20+20}{4}{
        \multido{\iB=0+2}{4}{%
            \psset{origin={\iA ,\iB}}
            \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!\iC](1,1)\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!\iC](1,1)(2,2)
            }
        }
    
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}}


%------------------------------%
%       Important Class        %
%------------------------------%
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt]{article}


\newcommand{\Cover}{

\ifthenelse{boolean{cover}{
\begin{titlepage}
\centering




\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{htw-berlin logo.jpg}
\end{figure}



{\LARGE\bfseries Modul:}


\vspace{2cm}

{\large Name:}\\
{\large Matrikelnummer:}

\vspace{0.1cm}

{Berlin, \today}





\end{titlepage}}{

\begin{titlepage}
\centering




\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{htw-berlin logo.jpg}
\end{figure}



{\LARGE\bfseries Prüfung im Modul:}


\vspace{2cm}

{\large Name:}\\
{\large Matrikelnummer:}

\vspace{0.1cm}

{Berlin, \today}





\end{titlepage}}
}

\endinput
```

.tex

```
\documentclass[htwLogo]{HTWself}



\begin{document}
\Cover

\newpage

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psgrid[
        gridcolor=black!20,
        subgriddiv=1,
        gridlabels=0pt
    ]
    \psaxes[
        ticks=all,
        mathLabel=false,
        showorigin=false,
        labelFontSize=\tiny
    ]{->}(0,0)(-5,-5)(5,5)[x,0][y,90]
\psset{algebraic}
\multido{\rP=1.5+-0.35,\iC=100+-20,\rV=0+0.5}{4}{
    \psplot[linewidth=\rP pt,linecolor=blue!\iC]{-3.5}{3.5}{0.005*x^(5)+\rV}
}

    
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Large 
                  {Hochschule für Technik und Wirtschaft Berlin}
l.119 \ProcessOptions\relax
                           
?
```

as `\Large` is undefined. It would be defined later, when you load `article` class, you should delay the processing until after the class is loaded.

Your construct

```
\DeclareOption{htwLogo}{
\setboolean{cover}{true}
\begin{document}
```

starting the document within the option is really weird and likely to produce many such errors. Starting it anywhere within the class is strongly discourged
The main tex file should have `\begin{document}` Actually it *has* `\begin{document}` so you have two, which can not work.

Also, your definition of `\Cover` is missing a closing `}`

Comment: Thx for the answer!
I wrote the \begin{document} in the bracets for my parameters because i get an Error if i am missing the \begin{document} for some reason. Also the Error is tagged on the line with the "\ProcessOptions\relax". 
I tried to move the "\ProcessOptions\relax" after the \LoadClass but then i add the
´LaTeX Error: \RequiredPackage or \LoadClass in options Section´

After my changes i added the ´Undefined control sequence.\set@color´ i guess this is some problem cause another package is defining color or am i wrong?

Comment: @Nutellafreak it is hard to guess what you want any of this code to do, I would guess your option should be just `\DeclareOption{htwLogo}{\setboolean{cover}{true}}` and move the pstricks in to the definition of `\Cover` so typesetting the pspicture happens within the document

Comment: Oh i am sry
The options of the class should either draw a chess board or a logo (with pstricks). For the Cover command i just wanna use a boolean to switch between 2 cover versions. For every class-option i have a different cover (two in total) so the boolean need to be set in ` \DeclareOption{} ` so the `\Cover` command can "react".

Comment: @Nutellafreak yes, as I say the option should just set the boolean then test the boolean in \Cover to draw or not draw pstricks

Comment: It took me some time but i managed to get a easier version of the command Cover to work as intended. But if i try to combine it with my class so the parameters set the boolean it doesnt work. There are no errors just warnings that doesnt produce the failure.

Still, thanks for your help